# Encoding a unicode prints the string correctly,but using a API for sending SMS ,sends the SMS with question marks

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encode

I want to send SMS in several languages.It works fine for english language.But if i want to send a SMS in French or Spanish,i have a problem.
The message is in Unicode.and after this

```
message = message.encode('utf-8')
```

the message is a string and prints the result correctly.But, when I want to use the API to send the message, it sends question marks(????????) instead of characters like  à, έ etc.I have tested it to my cell phone.
When I do message[0], it gives me "?". So i guess the encode('utf-8') doesn't work properly.The message contains French or Spanish or German or whatever characters.It is a variable, so every time contains different languages.
Here is a sample of my code:

```
to = queue_mobile 
message = queue_message
gateway = AfricasTalkingGateway(username, apikey)

try:
    results = gateway.sendMessage(to, message)
    for recipient in results:
        print 'number=%s;status=%s;messageId=%s;cost=%s' % (recipient['number'],
                                                                        recipient['status'],
                                                                        recipient['messageId'],
                                                                        recipient['cost'])
```

Without encoding the message, it returns an exception from the API (ascii codec can't encode characters 0-6 ).
If i encode('utf-8') the message, it sends the SMS but with question marks.

Answer (score 0):

Which api do you use?
Can you show some example code?
What charsets does your sms gateway support?

In GSM, there are different 7bit charsets for each language.

Maybe this can help:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7_bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38